Answer on "Ism" question possibly wrongly bot-flagged and deleted
Question on English.SE: Ists and anti-ists
Bot-deleted answer:
https://english.stackexchange.com/a/624896/142322
The question was about -isms, a construct which can be associated with polemics. However, the question itself seems to be squarely on-topic for English.SE, and based on revision history, the deleted answer seems like legitimate, on-topic, polite discourse.
However, the Community bot has flagged the answer "as spam or offensive content", and has hidden the answer text and locked the answer. There doesn't seem to be any way for non-mods to dredge it out of the bot's jail.
The person who answered has been a member for about 50 days. Their profile says this is just their second answer offered.
It seems to go against "be nice" to leave their answer hidden and locked. Unless I missed something shocking in their original answer or a later edit, would it be possible to reverse the Community bot's decision for this answer? The answer seems to be a reasonable contribution from a new English.SE user.

Community bot deletes and locks posts when they get four spam/rude flags from regular users, or one from a moderator—in this case me. It's not a mistake, not the first time nor these other two times on the answers I missed.
There's a new, devious type of spam, one that's only arisen in the last two years: Post an AI-generated answer (such as one from ChatGPT) and add a spam link. (Occasionally it's a question instead.) Please flag these, or if you're not sure, ask in Charcoal if they think it's spam. I'd also advise against clicking on any of these links.

You might want to link to the actual room (https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) not the transscript

For clarification, the spam link is not on the  day of posting but edited in two or even three days after.

You're absolutely right! Look out for telltale words like 'delve', cliches like 'Let's break it down.', and out of context enthusiasm like 'You’re absolutely right!'. These are hints, not guarantees, that the text is LLM generated. Thanks for your input!

Thanks. I was looking at the text of the answer and didn’t realise it contained a link, let alone a spam link.
